# Get jsondata value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**JSON**

```
   var jsondata={"id": "10", "skills": "english", "post": "devloper", "emp_name": "jaydeep","timestemp":"10:45"}
```

I am trying to get each element key and value:

**javascript**

```
..
}).done(function(data){
    console(data['post']);
});
```

**Expected Output :**

emp_name = jaydeep

post = devloper

I am getting undefined in console. WHY? I tried data.post, i tried loop but no success..

Comment: try data.post to get post key value

Comment: @NagaSaiA that is the exact same. JayDeep, Try JSON.parse(data)["post"]

Comment: What is data.post ? Where are you expect to get json? I don't see any jsondata vars in your code.

Comment: is the response returning what you expected?

Comment: i have output only : emp_name

Comment: what do you mean? try logging the entire response or view it in the developer console, i  think you are not getting the response you are expecting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic JS too to attain this.

```js
// property is an optional parameter.
function disp(obj, property) {
  var prop;
  if (property) {
    obj[property] && (console.log(obj[property]));
  } else {
    for (prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop])
      }
    }
  }
}
var jsondata = {
  "id": "10",
  "skills": "english",
  "post": "devloper",
  "emp_name": "jaydeep",
  "timestemp": "10:45"
}
//disp(jsondata, "post");
disp(jsondata);
```

Comment: The .done signifies an Ajax request is used to get the data

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to decode the JSON first.

```
}).done(function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console(data['post']);
});
```

Comment: as commented by me